# How to implement usage site variance in implicits?

Tags: scala, implicit, contravariance, invariance

Large redaction of the original question: now I present the whole code upfront, without showing the variants explaining my motivation. Apologies for the confusion.

I need a simple type class implementing a projection on one of type's member types - for the purpose of this example lets make it a straightforward cast:

```
trait Subject {
    type E
    type Const 
}

object Subject {
    implicit def projection :Projection[Subject] { type Project[X] = Subject { type E = X } } = ???
}

abstract class Projection[S <: Subject] {
    type Project[X] <: Subject { type E = X }
}

implicit class ProjectSubject[S <: Subject](private val self :S) extends AnyVal {
    def project[X](implicit p :Projection[S]) :p.Project[X] = ???
}

class Box[X] extends Subject { type E = X }

object Box {
    implicit def projection[A] :Projection[Box[A]] { type Project[X] = Box[X] } = ???
}

class Adapter[S <: Subject] extends Subject { type E = S#E }

object Adapter {
    implicit def adapterProjection[S <: Subject](implicit p :Projection[S])
        :Projection[Adapter[S]] { type Project[X] = Adapter[p.Project[X]] } = ???
}

val res = new Adapter[Box["E"]].project["F"]
```

In the example above, it is clear that the projection should be recursive, with `Subject` subclasses declaring their own rules. Obviously, I'd like the projection to be contravariant in effect:

```
class Specific extends Adapter[Box["E"]]
val spec = (new Specific).project["F"] //doesn't compile
```

If `Specific` does not provide its own projection, the one for `Adapter` should be used, with the last expression evaluating to `Adapter[Box["F"]]`. This works nicely if I declaer `Projection[-S <: Subject]`, but the problem is that I need the projections to preserve some properties, here expressed as the `Const` member type:

```
class Projection[S <: Subject] { 
    type Project[X] <: Subject { type E = X; type Const = S#Const }
}
```

I dropped this constraint from the code above for clarity, as it doesn't contribute to the problem.

In the previous example, the compiler will complain about the lack of an implicit `Projection[Specific]`, without trying to upcast the value. How to make it compile with usage site variance?

Not with existentials:

```
implicit class ProjectSubject[S <: Subject](private val self :S) extends AnyVal {
    def project[X](implicit p :Projection[_ >: S <: Subject]) = ???
}
```

My guess was that the wildcard here is equivalent to `Subject` and no implicits other than `Projection[Subject]` will be searched for from the compiler `-Xlog-implicits` logs of the unabridged problem (which had a large Subject hierarchy with more implicit projection declarations).

I then tried the trick with an intermediate contravariant implicit, which sometimes works:

```
abstract class ProjectionAvailable[-S <: T, T <: Subject] //extends (S => T)
implicit def ProjectionAvailable[S <: Subject](implicit p :Projection[S]) :ProjectionAvailable[S, S] = ??? //(s :S) => s

implicit def ProjectionSubject[S <: T, T <: Subject](s :S)(implicit witness :ProjectionAvailable[S, T]) =
    new ProjectionSubject[T](s)

class ProjectionSubject[S <: Subject](private val self :S) extends AnyVal {
    def project[X](implicit p :Projection[S]) :p.Project[X] = p.asInstanceOf[p.Project[X]]
}
```

This looked promising, but unfortunately the compiler goes about this exactly as before: looks at the available implicit, instantiates type parameters as `ProjectionAvailable[Specific, T]` and complains for the lack of `Projection`, without taking advantage of its contravariance. I tried a variant with

```
class ProjectionAvailable[S <: T, T <: Subject]
```

without any real difference apart for a more clear error. I tried integrating
the `ProjectionAvailable` into `Projection`, but it also changed nothing:

```
class Projection[-S <: T, T] { /* as before */ }
```

My hunch is that it probably is doable, but requires crafty guiding the compiler by hand in type inference and for now I am out of new avenues to explore.

Comment: Your code is not self-contained. What is `Adapter`? What is `Box`? Should it be `implicit def adapterProjection[S <: Subject](implicit p: Projection[S])...`? Without `p` being implicit you defined an implicit conversion, not an instance of type class. The line `val spec = new Specific.project["F"]` doesn't compile.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it seems like some lines were lost on copy&paste. Updated.

Comment: I guess `implicit def boxProjection[E]: Projection[Box[E]] { type Project[X] = Box[X] } = ???` also should be defined.

Comment: How do you test that `def project[X](implicit p :Projection[_ >: S <: Subject]) = ???` or approach with `ProjectionAvailable` do not work for you?

Comment: And what version of Scala do you use?

Comment: Yes, the implicit projection for every type in this problem is implicitly assumed to be defined - I omited it as it was obvious, but in hindsight I probably shouldn't have. I use Scala 2.13.2.

Comment: The problem is that I don't understand how you made your conclusions that approaches with existential `Projection` and `ProjectionAvailable` do not work (see my answer). Please provide details how you test your code.

Comment: Thanks for updated version of your question. I'm not sure why you keep saying that existential version doesn't work (while the version with `ProjectionAvailable` doesn't, indeed). The code seems to compile in 2.13.2 https://scastie.scala-lang.org/cGH7XlfMRSiZVPltFBGuLA (you can see `NotImplementedError`, it's a runtime exception because of `???`, so the code compiles). If the existential version really doesn't work for you for some reason, please explain why and how you test this (so that I could reproduce behavior you observe).

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce behavior you mentioned (that's why I asked in comments how you test that `def project[X](implicit p :Projection[_ >: S <: Subject]) = ???` or approach with `ProjectionAvailable` do not work for you).

With your approach with existential `Projection` in `ProjectSubject` I additionally defined `Projection[Specific]` and the code doesn't compile with error

```
Error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both value specificProjection in object App of type App.Projection[App.Specific]{type Project[X] = App.Specific}
 and method adapterProjection in object App of type [S <: App.Subject](implicit p: App.Projection[S]): App.Projection[App.Adapter[S]]{type Project[X] = App.Adapter[p.Project[X]]}
 match expected type App.Projection[_ >: App.Specific <: App.Subject]
  val spec = (new Specific).project["F"]
```

so the implicit for `Projection[Specific]` is among candidates and I can't see how the following can be true

> The wildcard here is equivalent to `Subject` and no implicits other than `Projection[Subject]` will be searched for.

If I make `adapterProjection` of lower priority than my additional implicit `Projection[Specific]` then

```
println(scala.reflect.runtime.universe.reify{
  (new Specific).project["F"]
}.tree)
```

prints

```
App.this.ProjectSubject(new App.this.Specific()).project["F".type](App.this.Implicits.specificProjection)
```

so it's `Projection[Specific]` that is selected.

Scala 2.13.3.

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Ts9UOx0aSfWuQJNOoVnSAA

Behavior for your original contravariant `Projection` (without type type `Const`) and the first `ProjectSubject` (with non-existential `Projection`) is the same.

(My answer in [In scala 2.13, how to use implicitly[value singleton type]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62747743/in-scala-2-13-how-to-use-implicitlyvalue-singleton-type) can be relevant.)

By the way, with invariant `Projection` and `ProjectionAvailable` I don't have to prioritize implicits and `Projection[Specific]` is selected.

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/nePYqjKGSWm8IRGLmYCwAA

And when I don't define additional implicit `Projection[Specific]` your approach with existential `Projection` seems to work, `adapterProjection` is selected. What's wrong with this behavior?

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/GiLoerYgT0OtxKyechezvA

Comment: Hi, first, thanks for the extent of time you put into this! Second, sorry for the late reply - I found a workaround (not one I am very much satisfied with) and this stopped being urgent. Third, I am not sure we are on the same page: did you define your projections in companion objects (and not, for example, in local scope or object Projection) ? Finally, the whole point of this question was for me the case when there *is no* projection defined for the `Specific` type, with the hope of using the one defined for Adapter.

Comment: The existentials still don't work for me: I'll edit the question to provide the full code gist. I wanted to introduce stuff gradually to better preserve my intent, but this obviously backfired.

Comment: @Turin Yeah, the full gist would be useful.

Comment: Done. The debugging snippet for the implicit used is amazing! I am now reading through your links.