# Extending a class with a type constructor

Tags: scala, generics, typeclass, implicit, existential-type

I'm trying to extend a base class with a single [A] type parameter, with a subclass that has an A[_] type parameter - like this:

```
abstract class IsBase[A]

abstract class IsSub[A[_]] extends IsBase[A[_]] {
  type T
  def get(self: A[T]): T 
}

implicit def listIsSub[_T] = new IsSub[List] {
  type T = _T;
  def get(self: List[T]): T = self(0)
}
val list = List(1, 2)

implicitly[IsSub[List]{ type T = Int }].get(list) // works fine
implicitly[IsBase[List[Int]]] // Could not find implicit value for parameter e
```

I understand one way to do this would just be to move the abstract type T up to a type parameter, likeso:

```
abstract class IsSub1[A[_], T] extends IsBase[A[T]]
```

But before I go ahead with this route I'd just like to check that there isn't a straightforward way to make this work as it is.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you need `IsSub` and `IsBase` for, but I'm pretty sure you have to make `T` a type parameter to `IsSub`. When you say `extends IsBase[A[_]]`, that `A[_]` is not the same as the `A[_]` type parameter. You are using a wildcard, which makes it pretty much useless. I'd recommend using `IsSub[A[_], T] extends IsBase[A[T]]` or something like that. It's a lot easier than using a structural type anyways.

Comment: You are declaring Base to take a full type, while declaring Sub to take a type constructor. They are different signatures. You need to be consistent. Other than declaring a second parameter T, you can also declare `IsBase[C[_]]` and then same for sub `IsSub[C[_]] extends IsBase[C]`

Comment: @user - thank you - I did mention that solution in my question but it's still nice to get some external validation. I get the impression that's the better long-term way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of [the first things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59348301/in-scala-2-or-3-is-it-possible-to-debug-implicit-resolution-process-in-runtime) you should try is to resolve the implicit manually and see what will happen

```
implicitly[IsBase[List[Int]]](listIsSub[Int])

//type mismatch;
// found   : App.IsSub[List]{type T = Int}
// required: App.IsBase[List[Int]]
//Note: List[_] >: List[Int] 
// (and App.IsSub[List]{type T = Int} <: App.IsBase[List[_]]), 
//  but class IsBase is invariant in type A.
//You may wish to define A as -A instead. (SLS 4.5)
```

So you can see that you just didn't define necessary implicit. You defined an implicit of type `IsSub[List]{type T = Int}`, which is not connected to `IsBase[List[Int]]` because `IsSub` (with type-constructor type parameter `A[_]`) extends `IsBase[A[_]]` with existential type parameter. Existentials (and type projections) [rarely](https://typelevel.org/blog/2015/07/23/type-projection.html) play well with implicits.

You can see the hint. You can make `IsBase` contravariant

```
abstract class IsBase[-A]
```

Then

```
implicitly[IsBase[List[Int]]]
```

compiles.

Whether to define your type class contravariant ([1](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/2509) [2](https://groups.google.com/g/scala-language/c/ZE83TvSWpT4/m/YiwJJLZRmlcJ) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64027726/how-to-handle-option-with-an-encoder-typeclass-in-scala) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62747743/in-scala-2-13-how-to-use-implicitlyvalue-singleton-type)) depends on your logic.

Comment: also - that typelevel blog series are really helpful, wish I had come across them earlier.