# In scala, how to make type class working for Aux pattern?

Tags: scala, typeclass, abstract-data-type, type-alias, scala-2.13

Here is a simple example:

```scala
  trait Base {

    type Out
    def v: Out
  }

  object Base {

    type Aux[T] = Base { type Out = T }

    class ForH() extends Base {

      type Out = HNil

      override def v: Out = HNil
    }

    object ForH extends ForH
  }

  class TypeClass[B]

  trait TypeClassLevel1 {

    def summon[B](b: B)(implicit ev: TypeClass[B]): TypeClass[B] = ev
  }

  object TypeClass extends TypeClassLevel1 {

    implicit def t1: TypeClass[Base.Aux[HNil]] = new TypeClass[Base.Aux[HNil]]

    implicit def t2: TypeClass[Int] = new TypeClass[Int]
  }

  it("No Aux") {

    val v = 2

    TypeClass.summon(v) // works
  }


  it("Aux") {

    val v = new Base.ForH()

    TypeClass.summon(v) // oops
    TypeClass.summon(Base.ForH) // oops

    val v2 = new Base.ForH(): Base.Aux[HNil]
    TypeClass.summon(v2) // works!
  }
```

The object Base/ForH clearly has a stable path, this eliminate the possibility of the compiler not being able to resolve type `ForH.Out`.

What bothers me is not how incapable the compiler is to figure out the fact that `ForH <:< Aux[HNil]`, but how easy it is to patch it up, just by a simple type upcast (last 2 lines). IMHO both features (type lambda & type classes) are important aspect of functional programming, why they can't work together at the same time?

If you are familiar with the compiler design I'll have an extra question: what does it take to improve the type class search algorithm to make it happen? Thanks a lot for your opinion.

**UPDATE 1**: a specific fix has been proposed but I have another problem trying to generalise it, please see [In scala, how to make type class working for Aux pattern? - Part 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65853961/in-scala-how-to-make-type-class-working-for-aux-pattern-part-2) for detail

Comment: `TypeClass` is invariant in `B`, so `TypeClass[Base.Aux[HNil]]` is not a subtype of `TypeClass[Base.ForH]`, neither the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the compiler is able to infer `ForH <:< Aux[HNil]`, but (tbh I don't know exactly why) when resolving an implicit when the return type uses a type lambda, it gets confused if you don't use a type bound.

Anyway that's probably not a great explanation, but at least I can make your code compile.  Just change `t1` to:

```
implicit def t1[T <: Base.Aux[HNil] ]: TypeClass[T] = new TypeClass[T]
```

this works for me in scastie using Scala 2.13.4.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good idea, but t2 works fine. You are right most type class should have a bound.

I'll keep the question hanging for a while just to see if a compiler insider can explain it

Comment: All compiler insiders have graduated :) accepted to give credit.
Please also refers to part 2 for other explanations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65853961/in-scala-how-to-make-type-class-working-for-aux-pattern-part-2

Answer (score 0):

> What bothers me is not how incapable the compiler is to figure out the fact that `ForH <:< Aux[HNil]`

Surely the compiler does see that `Base.ForH <:< Base.Aux[HNil]`. You can check that

```
implicitly[Base.ForH <:< Base.Aux[HNil]]
```

compiles.

> IMHO both features (type lambda & type classes) are important aspect of functional programming, why they can't work together at the same time?

Why are you talking about type lambdas? I can't see type lambdas in your question.

By the way, type lambdas is not a part of Scala 2 and `({ type λ[X] = ...F[X]... })#λ` for a type lambda is more or less a hack. Actual type lambdas are added to Scala 3.

`val v = new Base.ForH()` has type `Base.ForH` (not `Base.Aux[HNil]` without upcasting via type ascription `val v = new Base.ForH(): Base.Aux[HNil]` or manual type specification `val v: Base.Aux[HNil] = new Base.ForH()`). `TypeClass.summon(v)` shouldn't compile since there is no implicit `TypeClass[Base.ForH]`. What implicit would you consider as a candidate? `TypeClass.t1`? But it's not a candidate, you can check that explicitly resolved

```
TypeClass.summon(v)(TypeClass.t1)
```

can't compile.

> what does it take to improve the type class search algorithm to make it happen?

Implicit search algorithm shouldn't be improved in this specific place. It works properly, as intended.

You can make the type class contravariant

```
class TypeClass[-B]
```

Then `TypeClass.t1` will be a candidate for `TypeClass[Base.ForH]` and `TypeClass.summon(v)` will compile.

[In scala 2.13, how to use implicitly[value singleton type]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62747743/in-scala-2-13-how-to-use-implicitlyvalue-singleton-type)